# Mercurial: Recommended way of sending a whole repository to someone

Tags: mercurial, export

I have done some programming and I have used Mercurial for source control. I now need to send all of my code to someone else (because they are going to take over).

Since all copies of a mercurial repository is a full and real repository my first thought is to first do a clone of my repository without an update and then zipping and emailing that clone. Is this a good way, or is there a better way?

For example when using the TortoiseHg Repository Explorer I can right-click on a changeset and under Export there are various options that looks like they could be doing something interesting, but I don't quite understand them or know which one to use.

Comment: Meta: Your suggestion works, and it's what Jason Webb suggestions, but bjlaub's suggestion of a bundle will be smaller and prettier.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you've suggested will work fine, but you can also use `hg bundle` to create a changegroup file encapsulating a compressed copy of the entire repository (see `hg help bundle` for the full details, or this page: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#bundle).

On your machine:

```
hg -R /path/to/repo bundle --all my_repo.hg
```

Then send `my_repo.hg` off to the other developer, who can clone directly from that:

```
hg clone my_repo.hg /path/to/new/clone
```

(Note: this sort of assumes you're working with linux, but I imagine TortoiseHg supports something similar, since this is a basic feature of Mercurial).

**EDIT:**  Looks like the equivalent using TortoiseHg would be to export a range of changesets as a bundle (see here: http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.9/patches.html#export-patches).  In this case, you want to select the very first changeset all the way up through the tip, and export as a bundle.

Comment: Thanks! Worked nicely. Can use the command-line on windows too :)

Answer (score 1):

Every folder is a complete copy of the repository.  Simply send the entire folder and they will have everything they need.

Alternatively you can clone a copy of the folder and send them the clone.  This would allow them to push changes back to you if needed in the future.